# How to use references (object values) at validation point in Joi?

Tags: javascript, joi

I am trying to conditionally validate a key `key1` based on the value of different key `key2`. The `key1` is from some set of values, lets say `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `key2` should be also constrained depending on the value of `key1`  `{a: ['a1','a2','a3'], b: ['b1','b2','b3'], c: ['c1','c2','c3'] }`.

If `key1` is `a` then `key2` has to be one of `['a1','a2','a3']` etc. The set of values of `key2` is not computable from `key1`.

I tried following schemas, using ref, hoping `joi.ref('key1')`, just gets me the value:

```
const obj = {a: ['a1','a2','a3'], b: ['b1','b2','b3'], c: ['c1','c2','c3'] }
const schema = {
  key1: joi.only(['a', 'b', 'c']),
  key2: joi.only(obj[joi.ref('key1')])
}
```

and I get the error:

> "Cannot call allow/valid/invalid with undefined"

I've tried it with options map specified:

```
const schema = {
  key1: joi.only(['a', 'b', 'c']),
  key2: joi.only(joi.ref('key1', {map: [['a', ['a1','a2','a3']],['b', ['b1','b2','b3']],['c', ['c1','c2','c3']]]}))
}
```

For `{key1:'a', key2:'a1'}` I get ValidationError:

> "child "key2" fails because ["key2" must be one of [ref:key1]]

But curiously `{key1:'a', key2:'a'}` gets validated without error, which suggests the fallback of `joi.ref` to the original value.

So refs did not work as expected lets try when and switch:

```
const schema = {
key1: joi.only(['a', 'b', 'c']),
key2: joi.when('key1', {switch: [{is: 'a', then: joi.only(['a1','a2','a3'])},{is: 'b', then: joi.only(['b1','b2','b3'])},{is: 'c', then: joi.only(['c1','c2','c3'])}]})
}
```

But this gets me only:

> "options must have at least one of 'then' or 'otherwise'"

And if I supply `otherwise`, it also requires `is`. Is there any simple way how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try two different approaches in order to solve your problem.

The first one  uses multiple [`Joi.when()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v7.2.2/API.md#anywhenref-options) conditions:

```
const schema = joi.object({
    key1: joi.array().items(joi.string().valid('a','b','c')).unique(),
    key2: joi.array()
        .when('key1', { is: ['a'], then: joi.array().items(joi.string().valid('a1','a2','a3')).unique(), otherwise: joi.forbidden() })
        .when('key1', { is: ['b'], then: joi.array().items(joi.string().valid('b1','b2','b3')).unique(), otherwise: joi.forbidden() })
        .when('key1', { is: ['c'], then: joi.array().items(joi.string().valid('c1','c2','c3')).unique(), otherwise: joi.forbidden() })
})
```

The second one uses the [`Joi.alternatives()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#alternatives---inherits-from-any) :

```
const schema = joi.alternatives().try(
joi.object({
    key1: joi.array().items(joi.string().valid('a')).unique().required(),
    key2: joi.array().items(joi.string().valid('a1','a2','a3')).unique().required()
}),
joi.object({
    key1: joi.array().items(joi.string().valid('b')).unique().required(),
    key2: joi.array().items(joi.string().valid('b1','b2','b3')).unique().required()
}),
joi.object({
    key1: joi.array().items(joi.string().valid('c')).unique().required(),
    key2: joi.array().items(joi.string().valid('c1','c2','c3')).unique().required()
}))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This certainly would work, however i was looking for something that would be more dynamic, depending on the 'obj' object.